Saving pager state from configuration change jetpack compose
How to save pagerState when configuration change occurs? RememberPagerState function does not have any parameter related to current page to be shown. I will be grateful for some suggestions to this
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun TrackScreenManager(navHostController: NavHostController) {
        val viewModel = koinViewModel<TrackScreenManagerViewModel>()
        val pagerValue = viewModel.pagerStateValue.collectAsState()
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = pagerValue.value) { 3 }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            ) { page ->
            when (page) {
                0 -> SettingsTrackScreen(navHostController)
                1 -> MainTrackScreen()
                2 -> StatisticsTrackScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}


Remember saveable or viewModel can't be used because rememberPagerState is compose function so i can't initialize it there
